# Git error 403 pushing

Tags: android, git, github

I am contributing in a repository. I can't push my code. Last week I pushed successfully my code, but today I can't. When I try to push I have this message:

> Failed with error: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Repository/Project.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

I tried to change the .git/config archive in many ways, but nothing worked. I have also tried to push using Android Studio, the desktop GitHub client, tortoise git and cmd but nothing works. I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar error. For my github account email verification was pending. Once Email verification was in place i was able to push my code to the repo.

There can be other reasons why you are not able to access the git repo but if you have recently created your github account please check if there are any warnings being shown when you login to your github account.

Comment: Thanks that was my problem

Comment: Nice catch. I was able to pull from the repo using Android Studio, but I couldn't push my own commits (got a 403). This solved it.

Answer (score 3):

The error code 403 means *Forbidden*.
You have no access to that Git repository.

Ask the maintainers of the repository to check your access.
Maybe they recently removed your access.

As you seem to push to an https:// URL, I suppose you have to enter your password. Make sure you got the password right.
As a sanity check, try to push to a repository that's under your account.
If that works, then the problem is the first: your access has been revoked.